# How to create a hollow div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 overlapping transparent `div`'s with their own buttons and other functionality like this:

```css
.item1{
  height:10rem;
  width:10rem;
  position:absolute;
  border:0.5rem solid red;
  background-color:transparent;
}

.item2{
  height:10rem;
  width:10rem;
  position:absolute;
  top:5rem;
  left:2rem;
  border:0.5rem solid blue;
  background-color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="item2">
  <button>button 2</button>
</div>

<div class="item1">
  <button>button 1</button>
</div>
```

but I want the divs to act hollow so that in the above example I can also press `button2`
is something like this even possible?

**Note:**
I'm not looking for a workaround divs
for eg. please do not suggest that I use SVG rectangles instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep pointer events on the button only

```css
.item1{
  height:10rem;
  width:10rem;
  position:absolute;
  border:0.5rem solid red;
  background-color:transparent;
}

.item2{
  height:10rem;
  width:10rem;
  position:absolute;
  top:5rem;
  left:2rem;
  border:0.5rem solid blue;
  background-color:transparent;
}

div[class] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
button {
  pointer-events: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="item2">
  <button>button 2</button>
</div>

<div class="item1">
  <button>button 1</button>
</div>
```

Comment: [This has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-div-to-underlying-elements)

Comment: ofc! how could I have missed this, thank you!

Comment: @evolutionxbox vote to close as duplicate instead of commenting

Comment: Thanks, I did, but I'm informing you since you didn't.

Comment: @evolutionxbox no need to inform me (or anyone in general), the question can be closed without me. You are simply adding noise to the comment section